# Periodic Error in Flutter: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

As soon as I start my App (it happens both in debug and profile mode), the following error occurs:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (12391): #0      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1108)
E/flutter (12391): #1      _PollCardViewState.updatePoll.<anonymous closure> (package:mobile_app/components/poll_card_view/poll_card_view.dart:58)
E/flutter (12391): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362)    
E/flutter (12391): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265)
E/flutter (12391): #4      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170)
E/flutter (12391): #5      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1207)
E/flutter (12391): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370)
E/flutter (12391): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265)
E/flutter (12391): #8      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1191)
E/flutter (12391): #9      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395)
E/flutter (12391): #10     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426)
E/flutter (12391): #11     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184)
E/flutter (12391):
```

The error happens periodically in the background and does not affect the app. In fact, the app seems to work just as always.

The error does not mention any of my widgets or different pages. I do not have any clue where this Null check operator is used on a null value.
Yesterday my app was just fine and this error did not happen.

I am **not** using Flutter Null Safety. But i did not use it from the beginning, and this error never happened before. Does anyone have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: could you post the contents of `_PollCardViewState.updatePoll()`

Comment: I don't have such a widget in my app. I think it's from the flutter framework?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be, perhaps a bug in a library you are using?

Comment: I dont know. Yesterday it was suddenly gone, today its here again. I dont have any idea as it does not mention any specific library. Hm... frustrating.